# sound stop when device sleeps flex mobile

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, sleep

I am developing a simple android mobile app using flex. I want to download an mp3 from internet and save it on SD card then play it.

my problems: 1. I can download and play the file but I can't save it as mp3
             2. when the device is idle for sometime and goes to sleep mode, the sound stops

how can i achieve that.

regards,

Answer (score 2):

I looked through the android PowerManager API and found the following working

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK" />
```

This will allow your process to run even after the user presses the power button or the screen went dim.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

Wake Lock Permission - If your player application needs to keep the screen from dimming or the processor from sleeping, or uses  MediaPlayer.setWakeMode() methods, you must request this permission.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: thanx, but i need to play the music even when the screen is dimmed. I don't want to keep the screen alive, even when the user press power button it should continue play. like any other music player